# Ingress subdomain shows -- after creating an ibm-cloud kubernetes cluster

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-cluster

I have a created an ibm cloud kubernetes cluster, on a single zone with 2 workers, but the ingress subdomain is not assigned. It shows *--*

Based on **troubleshooting cluster network** documentation, this can happen if the maximum number (40) of subnets in a VLAN of a zone is reach. But it's not the case on my cluster, after checking the **Network > IP Management > VLANs** I only have 10 subnets existing.

When I run the command

```sh
ibmcloud ks cluster-get --cluster mycluster | grep Ingress
```

I have:

```
Ingress Subdomain:      -   
Ingress Secret:         -
```

Below is the overview of my cluster the ibm cloud dashboard.

[image: Cluster overview in ibmcloud dashboard]

I was expecting to have a generated subdomain based on the format specified in the ibm cloud documentation to access my application on a public network.

Please help me if identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue too, but it only happened to a shared account. I have been told it cloud be due to the drain of IPs assigned to the shared account under a certain region. The cluster created under my own account is fine with the creation of external IP and subdomain name.

I suggest you try to create your cluster in another region to see how it goes. Be ware of what type of account you are using as well.